# Pyaudio "Invalid input device (no default output device)" on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: audio, amazon-ec2, pyaudio

I'm trying to use pyaudio with Python 3 on an EC2 AWS instance running "Amazon Linux 2 AMI 2.0.20190618 x86_64 HVM gp2" or Ubuntu (same result for both).

I started by getting the Python 3 version of Anaconda and installed pyaudio with conda. However, when I actually try to use pyaudio, there are no devices available. Same thing if I try installing with pip (which requires installing gcc first, then building and installing PortAudio from sources and then only pyaudio).

```py
import pyaudio
pa = pyaudio.PyAudio()
pa.get_device_count()
>> 0
```

I've ran this in a python shell I started after sshing into the instance from my machine, and also in a Jupyter notebook I'm running on the instance and accessing from my browser. The end goal is to have audio recording available in that notebook. When trying to use `pa.open(...)`, the error is:

```
...
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyaudio.py in __init__(self, PA_manager, rate, channels, format, input, output, input_device_index, output_device_index, frames_per_buffer, start, input_host_api_specific_stream_info, output_host_api_specific_stream_info, stream_callback)
    439 
    440         # calling pa.open returns a stream object
--> 441         self._stream = pa.open(**arguments)
    442 
    443         self._input_latency = self._stream.inputLatency

OSError: [Errno -9996] Invalid input device (no default output device)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is the machine does not have an audio card

```
aplay --list-devices  #  list recognized audio hardware
```

aplay is a portaudio utility ... to install issue

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-utils
```

show audio drivers in use

```
sudo /sbin/lsmod | grep snd
```

If audio hardware exists, audio driver install is OS specific ... What OS are you using ?

Get pulseaudio package installed then run above aplay to see if it lists any audio cards

You have two unknowns - does the server hardware have an audio card ...  if yes then get your audio drivers installed and if not then question becomes is it possible to use pyaudio on server without audio card

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is the OS: https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-2/
It's a virtual machine hosted by Amazon, so it doesn't have hardware per say, need to make it use my own.

Comment: As for your suggestions, the package manager is yum, not apt-get. aplay's not available. I can install pulseaudio-utils, but what was that for? As expected, no audio hardware listed.

Comment: I tried an Ubuntu OS to make sure it wasn't just because of that weird Amazon one, same thing. The aplay command returns "aplay: device_list:270: no soundcards found...". So the answer's no, but shouldn't it be possible to use my local sound devices? Especially when running code in a browser. I read some things about dummy sound cards but not sure what to do exactly :/ Could also always use something else than pyaudio if there's other libraries for playing/recording wave files that'll work...